# Merge multiple files recursively in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

My folder path structure in HDFS is something like this:

```
/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=00
/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=01
/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=02
/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=03
```

Inside these paths I have many small size json files. I am writing a shell script which can merge all files present inside all these individual directories into a single individual filename depending on path.

Example:

All JSONs inside /data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=00 into one merged file full_2017_02_28_00.json

All JSONs inside /data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=01 into one merged file full_2017_02_28_01.json

All JSONs inside /data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=02 into one merged file full_2017_02_28_02.json and so on.

Keeping the file name in the above said pattern is secondary job which I will try to achieve. Currently I can hardcode the filenames.

But, recursive concatenation inside directory path structure is not happening.

So far, I have tried below:

```
hadoop fs -cat /data/topicname/year=2017/* | hadoop fs -put - /merged/test1.json
```

Error:-

```
cat: `/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=00': Is a directory
cat: `/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=01': Is a directory
cat: `/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28/hour=02': Is a directory
```

Recursive cat is not happening in above try

```
hadoop fs -ls /data/topicname/year=2017/month=02 | find /data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28 -name '*.json' -exec cat {} \; > output.json
```

Error:-

```
find: ‘/data/topicname/year=2017/month=02/day=28’: No such file or directory
```

It is doing find in local FS instead of HDFS in above attempt

```
for i in `hadoop fs -ls -R /data/topicname/year=2017/ | cut -d' ' -f19` ;do `hadoop fs -cat $i/* |hadoop fs -put - /merged/output.json`; done
```

Error:-

```
cannot write output to stream message is repeated multiple times
file /merged/output.json is repeated a few times
```

How is this achievable? I do not want to use Spark.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`-appendToFile`](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#appendToFile):

```
for file in `hdfs dfs -ls -R /src_folder | awk '$2!="-" {print $8}'`; do hdfs dfs -cat $file | hdfs dfs -appendToFile - /target_folder/filename;done
```

Time taken will be dependent on the number and size of files as the process is sequential.

Comment: This is taking a lot of time. It ran for like 20 minutes and was able to append only some 10-15 files with merged file size as 5MB

Comment: Yes, using fsshell is sequential and will be slow. This solution is the syntactically correct version for the question you have posted. To achieve parallelism, use MapReduce or Spark (which you have mentioned as do no want to use).

Answer (score -1):

I was able to achieve my goal with below script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for k in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12
do
        for j in 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
        do
                for i in 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
                do

                hadoop fs -cat /data/topicname/year=2017/month=$k/day=$j/hour=$i/* | hadoop fs -put - /merged/TEST1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i.json
                hadoop fs -du -s /merged/TEST1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i.json > /home/test/sizetest.txt
                x=`awk '{ print $1 }' /home/test/sizetest.txt`
                echo $x
                if [ $x -eq 0 ]
                then
                hadoop fs -rm /merged/TEST1/2017"_"$k"_"$j"_"$i.json
                else
                echo "MERGE DONE!!! All files generated at hour $i of $j-$k-2017 merged into one"
                echo "DELETED 0 SIZED FILES!!!!"
                fi

                done
        done
done

rm -f /home/test/sizetest.txt
hadoop fs -rm -r /data/topicname
```